# Solving odd repetitions in scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp

I'm trying to solve a problem with outputting only the non repeating elements n a list in scheme. e.g: `'(a b a a a c c)` would give `(a b)`.

I have implemented this solution:

```
(define (remove L)  
  (if (null? L)
      L
      (let ((firstL (car L)) (restL (cdr L)))        
        (if (null? restL)
            (cons firstL ())
            (if (equal? firstL (car restL))
                (remove (cdr restL))                
                (cons firstL (remove restL)))))))
```

However it outputs the also the elements with odd number of repetitions. e.g: (a b a a a c c) would give (a b a).

I'm trying to fix it, but I couldn't. an example of one of the solutions that I have tried is:

```
(define (remove L)  
  (if (null? L)
      L      
      (let ((result ()) (firstL (car L)) (restL (cdr L)))        
        (if (null? restL)
            (result)            
            (if (equal? firstL (car restL))
                (remove2 firstL restL)                
                (append ((list firstL) result))
                (remove cdr restL)))))

  (define (remove2 x y)
    (cond ((null? y) (remove x)
                     ((equal? x (car y)) (remove2 ((car y) (cdr y))))                     
                     (else (remove x)))))
```

Please if someone can figure a solution, write it down.

Answer (score 0):

Your second attempt has lots of syntactic errors. I think if you look at the first attempt and mend one syntax error with the missing quote `'()` you almost have it if you can remove successive elements instead of just one. eg. make

```scm
(trim-first '(a b c))     ; ==> (b c)
(trim-first '(a a b c))   ; ==> (b c)
(trim-first '(a a a b c)) ; ==> (b c)
```

Then you could just use that instead of `cdr`:

```scm
(define (remove L)  
  (if (null? L)
      L
      (let ((firstL (car L)) (restL (cdr L)))        
        (if (null? restL)
            (cons firstL '())
            (if (equal? firstL (car restL))
                (remove (trim-first restL))                
                (cons firstL (remove restL)))))))
```

I would have written it with `cond` to make it flatter though and kept away from the unconventional `camelCase` in favor of `lisp-case`:

```scm
(define (remove-runs lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) '())
        ((null? (cdr lst)) lst)
        ((equal? (car lst) (cadr lst)) (remove-runs (trim-first (cdr lst))))
        (else (cons (car lst) (remove-runs (cdr lst))))))
```

Comment: is trim-first a built-in function in scheme? or do I have to implement it?

Comment: @Maha No, you'll need to implement it. In my answer I'm specifying how its supposed to work. I guess this is homework so I'm scared I'll ruin your education if I help you too much :)

Comment: It's not a hw i'm preparing for my final exam. Thanks for your help.

Comment: (define (trim L2)
  (cond 
        ((null? L2)'())
        ((equal? (car L2) (cadr L2)) (trim (cdr L2)))
        (else (remove (cadr L2)))))

Comment: I wrote this function but it gives me an error that says an attempt to apply cdr on c.this is the list i'm applying it on (a b a a a c c f ).

Comment: I FIGURED IT OUT THANKS ALOT!!

Answer (score 0):

Following is a solution in Racket (Scheme derivative) using "named let" recursion. The sent list is divided into its components as `'((a)(b)(a a a)(c c))` and then only those sublists are taken which have only one item:

```
(define (f l)
  (let loop ((l (rest l))              ; first item removed from sent list
             (ol '())        ; store repeating sequences here as separate lists
             (temp (list(first l))))   ; keep first item in temp
    (cond
      [(empty? l)                      ; end reached
       ; (println (cons temp ol))      ; here temp+ol is '((c c)(a a a)(b)(a))
       (reverse
        (flatten
         (filter
          (λ (x) (= 1 (length x)) )    ; take only those which have only one item
          (cons temp ol))))]
      [(equal? (first l) (first temp)) ; if item repeats, store together
       (loop (rest l)
             ol
             (cons (first l) temp) )]
      [else                            ; else put temp in ol & start new temp
       (loop (rest l)
             (cons temp ol)
             (list (first l)))])))
```

Testing:

```
(f '(a b a a a c c))
```

Output:

```
'(a b)
```